# Why isn't the Charikar algorithm for finding the densest subgraph optimal?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, approximation

I read about the algorithm in
[Greedy Approximation Algorithms for Finding
Dense Components in a Graph](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.1184&rep=rep1&type=pdf) by
Moses Charikar,
and I tried to find an instance/graph where the algorithm returns a different solution from the optimal one but I didn't succeed.
Can anyone provide me an example where the algorithm 'fails' and proves that the approximation is no less than 2?

Comment: I am a little confused by the downvotes. Seems like a legitimate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have a complete graph on four nodes and then next to it a graph with five nodes comprising a degree four hub and four degree 3 satellites. The greedy algorithm might start by removing one of the satellites and thus spoil the optimum which is 1.6

`o-------o    o-------o
| \   / |    | \   / |
|   X   |    |   o   |
| /   \ |    | /   \ |
o-------o    o-------o`

For the sake of completeness: given a graph $G=(V,E)$ the task is to find a subset $S\subseteq V$ maximising the quantity $|E(S)| / |S|$ where $E(S)\subseteq E$ is the set of edges with endpoints in $S$. The greedy algorithm operates by successively removing vertices of minimal degree and then searching for the optimal $S$ among the successively shrinking set of remaining vertices.

Comment: Is this counterexample "tight"? i.e., does it show that 2 is indeed the best approximation ratio that the algorithm respects?